# Regex match specific strings

Tags: regex

I want to capture all the strings from multi lines data. Supposed here the result and here’s my code which does not work.

Pattern: ^XYZ/[0-9|ALL|P] I’m lost with this part anyone can help?

```
Result
XYZ/1
XYZ/1,2-5
XYZ/5,7,8-9
XYZ/2-4,6-8,9
XYZ/ALL
XYZ/P1
XYZ/P2,3
XYZ/P4,5-7
XYZ/P1-4,5-7,8-9

Changed to
XYZ/1
XYZ/1,2-5
XYZ/5,7,8-9
XYZ/2-4,6-8,9
XYZ/A12345 after the slash limited to 6 alphanumeric chars
XYZ/LH-1234567890 after the /LH- limited to 10 numeric chars
```

Comment: What are the requirements for the last part? `[0-9|ALL|P]` just matches a single char, `A`, `L`, `P`, `|`, or a digit.

Comment: In order to write a regular expression, you must first express in English what the rules are that you're trying to match.  So what are the rules you want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern could be:

```
^XYZ\/(?:ALL|P?[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+)?(?:,[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+)?)*)$
```

The pattern in parts matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `XYZ\/` Match `XYX/` (You don't have to escape the `/` depending on the pattern delimiters)
- `(?:` Outer on capture group for the alternatives

  - `ALL` Match literally
  - `|` Or
  - `P?` Match an optional `P`
  - `[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional `-` and 1+ digits
  - `(?:` Non capture group to match as a whole

    - `,[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+)?` Match `,`and 1+ digits and optional `-` and 1+ digits
  - `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it
- `)` Close the outer non capture group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2hJjLC/1)

Comment: Hi @The fourth bird, thank you for the answer, it works but it matches if the string is XYZ/0123456 it should be matched only for XYZ/ followed by the number or number then dash or comma.

Comment: @ClintMohamed Then you can omit the quantifier for the digits `^XYZ\/(?:ALL|P?[0-9](?:-[0-9])?(?:,[0-9](?:-[0-9])?)*)$` https://regex101.com/r/hfOeuQ/1

Comment: Hi @The fourth bird, something has changed I want to match this only XYZ/1
XYZ/1,2-5
XYZ/5,7,8-9
XYZ/2-4,6-8,9
XYZ/A12345 after the slash limited to 6 alphanumeric chars
XYZ/LH-1234567890 after the /LH- limited to 10 numeric chars

Comment: @ClintMohamed Like this? https://regex101.com/r/FMx1E8/1 `^XYZ\/(?:[A-Z0-9]{6}|LH-[0-9]{10}|P?[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+)?(?:,[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+)?)*)$`

Comment: It’s matching XYZ/1234567

Comment: @ClintMohamed Ow yes, it should be without the quantifier for the digits https://regex101.com/r/8N2XHg/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex pattern to match those lines

```
^XYZ\/(?:P|ALL|[0-9])[0-9,-]*$
```

Use the global `g` and multiline `m` flags.

Btw, `[P|ALL]` doesn't match the word "ALL".
It only matches a single character that's a `P` or `A` or `L` or `|`.